# Why does setting state in child component onclick cause recursive loop even when button not clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand why when I try to set state on a child component button onclick event it causes a recursive loop.

For instance this code generates the error:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({ name: "Joe" });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child state={formState} setState={setFormState} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ state, setState }) {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <h1>Name:{state.name}</h1>
      <button onClick={setState({ name: "Bill" })}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

This error occurs on render without a button click. How can it cause recursion on compile without even a click being sent?  I do not understand what is going on here.

The error goes if I use an arrow function like so:

```
function Child({ state, setState }) {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <h1>Name:{state.name}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setState({ name: "Bill" })}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I kind of understand that the arrow function changes `this` but the finer points of what is happening here are alluding me.

Can someone tell me:

1. Why does calling it without arrow cause recursive loop?
2. How does arrow fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On this line

```
<button onClick={setState({ name: "Bill" })}>Next</button>
```

What you think you are doing is assigning `setState` with the argument `{name: "Bill" }` to the onClick handler of the element. This is not the case.

What you're actually doing is *calling* the `setState` function *during* the render, which changes the state and causes a rerender to occur. In the rerender, `setState` is called which changes the state and causes a rerender to occur; in the rerender, `setState` is called, etc.

With `onClick={()=> {setState({name:"Bill"})}` you create and assign the arrow function to the onClick handler. When the element is clicked, the arrow function executes and setState is called inside.

Comment: Thank you so much that is a really good explanation.  I was getting so lost reading on arrow functions and this actually clears it up for me and explains the behaviour I didn't understand.